# Convert system time as string to Timestamp

Tags: java, date, timestamp, simpledateformat, time-format

I’m trying to get the time of my computer using Java and format it in specific order using `SimpleDateFormat` object but it won't format; please help.

This is my code :

```
java.util.Date parsedDate = null;      
try {   
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");  
    parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date()));
}catch(ParseException e){
}  
Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
```

Comment: (1) Please be specific about the desired result and how the observed result differs. (2) Don’t swallow exceptions. This one in particular might give us important information about what goes wrong. (3) `SimpleDateFormat` is long outdated and notoriopusly troublesome. I recommend [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), instead. (4) A `Timestamp` does not and cannot hold a format in it. It is only a point in time.

Comment: *Never* write an empty catch block.  Exceptions tell you what went wrong and where—if you ignore them, you make troubleshooting your code extremely difficult.  At the very least, a catch block needs to show the stack trace, such as with `e.printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime
    .now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) 
    .toString()
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome troublesome old legacy classes that are now supplanted by the modern java.time classes. Avoid the old classes entirely.

Get the current moment in UTC with a resolution of up to nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

To see that same moment through a particular region’s wall-clock time, apply a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atone( z ) ;
```

To work with only a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone, extract a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

If by "format to specific order" you meant sorting… These objects know how to sort. No need for a string just for sorting.

```
List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList<>() ;
times.add( lt ) ;
…
Collections.sort( times ) ;
```

Generate a String for display to user. The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default for generating/parsing strings.

```
String output = lt.toString() ;
```

For other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "HH:mm" ) ;
String output = lt.format( f ) ;
```

All of this has been handled many times on Stack Overflow. Search for more info and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Hi user8545027 i modified you code a little bit and it works for me now. I also used ThreadLocal to make SimpleDateFormat safe for MultiThreading.

```
package com.java;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    private ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> threadSafeDateFormat = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
        @Override
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        }
    };

    String formatDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = threadSafeDateFormat.get();
        String timeStamp = format.format(new Date());
        return timeStamp;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.formatDate());
    }
}
```

Let me know if any questions. Hope this Helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
public class Basics {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String date = dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println(date);   
  }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see what difference it should make. Do you get two different results from the two code lines on your computer?

Comment: with the above code the result am getting is  "1970-01-01 21:49:00.0"  Hope this what you are looking for.

Comment: It didn't work , the result that I'm looking for is 21:49

Comment: Just clock without date

Comment: I would like to suggest you an answer try this,

Comment: DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String date = dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(date);

Comment: If this is what you are looking for please let me know i'll edit and update my answer:)

Comment: Still the same result &quot;1970-01-01 08:49:00.0&quot;

Comment: It works if you want i'll upload the image of output console. If you are still struggling to know how to get it work please lemme know what you are not getting.

Comment: i told you what i'm not getting the result is i'm getting it :"1970-01-01 08:49:00.0" and i want just the clock in the following format : "08:44"-->"HH:mm"

Comment: it works but when i convert it to java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp it returns to the last format how can i solve this

Comment: I only way i can suggest you is save the time as it is in millis(long value) to the database. Then while retrieving the time information from database format it  and use the way you want for further requirement:)